# Vue JS : Flush / reload the whole tree-view

Tags: javascript, treeview, hierarchical-data, vue.js

I am new to Vue JS.
Just implemented a sample Tree view.

How do I flush the whole tree-view and reload it with new content entirely?

Went through the Vue API's but failed to find any.

Please help.

Comment: show us your code if you want help

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to this: http://vuejs.org/examples/tree-view.html

There is no special method nessessary for this. you would simply replace the data with new data:

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    treeData: data
  },
  methods: {
    //call this method e.g. from a buttons click event.
    flushtree: function() {
      this.treeData = newData // get new Data from somehwere.
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. 

BTW any idea on how to stop adding child node at some point (disabling dbl click event or stop the recursive behavior at some child node) ?

Comment: I would add a prop `depth` and increase it with each recursive call. Then check in the click handler if `depth < 10`or something, depending on what you condition is.

Answer (score 0):

My modified code snippet:

```
if(demo!=null) {
    demo.flushtree(tableJson);
} else {
    demo = new Vue({
    data: {
     treeData: tableJson
    },
    methods: {
        flushtree: function(newData) {
        this.treeData = newData;
    }
}
})
demo.$mount('#demo');
}
```

Thanks :)